# Producer consumer using a bounded Channel<T>, with strict memory allocation requirements

Tags: c#, optimization, producer-consumer, memory-efficient, system.threading.channels

Here is my scenario¹. I have a producer consumer system that is composed by two producers, one consumer, and a bounded [`Channel<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1) configured with capacity 2. The `T` is `byte[]`.

```
Channel<byte[]> channel = Channel.CreateBounded<byte[]>(2);
```

The `byte[]`s propagated through the channel are huge (1GB each), which creates the need to limit the total number of the arrays that exist at any given moment to a minimum. So the two producers are waiting before creating a `new byte[1_000_000_000]`, until they know that there is empty space in the channel. Here is the first producer:

```
Task producer1 = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        await channel.Writer.WaitToWriteAsync();

        // The channel has space available. Let's create the array.
        byte[] array = new byte[1_000_000_000];

        // Here initialize the array (mainly I/O bound, time consuming)

        // At this moment the channel might be full,
        // because the other producer filled the gap.
        await channel.Writer.WriteAsync(array);
    }
});
```

The second producer is identical. Unfortunately this allows both producers to start creating a new array, even when there is only one empty slot in the channel. So at some moment the system might have 4 huge arrays alive at the same time: 1 consumed by the consumer, 1 stored in the channel, and 2 created concurrently be the two producers (trying to fill a single empty slot).

I want to limit the total number of arrays in managed memory to 3. Is there any way that I can tame my producers, so that they don't start creating a new `byte[]` until there is certainly space available for it in the channel? In other words after creating an array, the producer should be able to write it immediately in the channel like this:

```
bool success = channel.Writer.TryWrite(array);
```

...and the `success` should always be `true`.

¹ <sub>This scenario is contrived. It was inspired by a [recent GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/76281).</sub>

---

**Clarification:** The construction and initialization of the byte arrays is the exclusive responsibility of the producer, and it should stay this way. Delegating the construction work elsewhere, either partially or fully, is not desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The construction and initialization of the byte arrays is the exclusive responsibility of the producer, and it should stay this way. Delegating the construction work elsewhere, either partially or fully, is not desirable.

In that case, you can use the limiter to limit "tokens", if you will, where each token is an authorization to allocate.

```
public sealed class TokenAllocator
{
  private readonly SemaphoreSlim _mutex;

  public TokenAllocator(int maxTokens) =>
      _mutex = new(maxTokens);

  public async Task<IDisposable> AllocateAsync()
  {
    await _mutex.WaitAsync();
    return Disposable.Create(() => _mutex.Release());
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var allocator = new TokenAllocator(3);
var channel = Channel.CreateBounded<(IDisposable token, byte[] item)>(2);

var consumer = Task.Run(async () =>
{
  await foreach (var (token, item) in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
  using (token)
  {
    ... // Do something with `item`
  }
});

var producer1 = Task.Run(async () =>
{
  while (true)
  {
    var token = await allocator.AllocateAsync();
    try
    {
      var item = new byte[1_000_000_000];
      ... // Do something with `item`
    }
    catch
    {
      token.Dispose();
      throw;
    }
    await channel.Writer.WriteAsync((token, item));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks also for this answer! Very nice, this seems like a simple and neat solution to the problem, that I can accept! Regarding the `Disposable.Create` method, is it coming from the System.Reactive package?

Comment: It could be. I usually use my own [Disposables package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/nito.disposables/).

Answer (score 3):

One option, although it requires a little manual management, would be a simple wrapper around a channel that limits the size.

```
public class LockingFixedPool<T>
{
    private readonly Channel<T> Items;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim locker;
    
    public LockingFixedPool(T[] seeded)
    {
        Items = Channel.CreateBounded<T>(seeded.Length);
        foreach (var element in seeded)
        {
            Items.Writer.TryWrite(element);
        }
    }
    public async Task<T> GetItemAsync()
    {
        return await Items.Reader.ReadAsync();
    }
    public void Release(T item)
    {
        //unless you make this specific to arrays,
        //you should clear before calling release.
        Items.Writer.TryWrite(item);
    }
}
```

The biggest problem with this 'bare' implementation, is that you have to manually manage when the item is released.
As an alternative, you could return a 'wrapped' instance:

```
public class LockPooledItem<T> : IDisposable
{
    public T Item {get;}
    private LockingFixedPool<T> _pool;
    public LockPooledItem(T item, LockingFixedPool<T> pool)
    {
        Item = item;
        _pool = pool;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _pool.Release(Item);
    }
}
```

And have LockingFixedPool return instances of those. OFC you'll then be allocating the tracking object, -but- it is a trade off between composition and manual code around managing the allocation.

Edit per comment:

```
//This is for the sake of simplicity in example
SingletonHolder.LockedGibiByteArrayPool = new LockingArrayPool<byte[]>(new [] { new byte[1_000_000_000], new byte[1_000_000_000] });
Task producer1 = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        await channel.Writer.WaitToWriteAsync();

        // Grab an array from our pool.
        byte[] array = await 
SingletonHolder.LockedGibiByteArrayPool.GetItemAsync();

        // Here initialize the array (mainly I/O bound, time consuming)

        // The channel should not be full,
        // But the reader -must- make sure to release the array
        // when it is done.
        // alternatively, use the 'LockPooledItem` pattern suggested,
        // and then at least it's just a `Dispose()` call...
        await channel.Writer.WriteAsync(array);
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more how the `LockingFixedPool` class fits in my producer-consumer system? What does the `T[] seeded` argument represent? Could you include a usage example? In my system there is not a predefined number of items that needs to be processed. The system might run for an eternity, with byte arrays produced and consumed ad infinitum.

Comment: I added a simple example based on your example usage.

Basically, the pool will allocate two 1Gb arrays -once-. until one is released, the example will wait at `GetItemAsync()`, thus the stressing that whatever reader is on the other end of `channel.Writer.WriteAsync()` -must- either release when done or call dispose if using `LockPooledItem`.

Comment: The 'Seeded' is basicaly pre-allocating the arrays to be used. This has a benefit of not lower GC Pressure overall, but you will have to make sure to clear the arrays at -some- stage or track how full they are for a given message.

Comment: Aha, so the `LockingFixedPool` is effectively an object pool. That's a clever idea, but it also imposes the constraint that the objects passed through the channel are reusable. Unfortunately that's too restrictive. I am searching for a general solution that will allow for non-reusable objects as well, that are simply garbage collected after the consumer is done with them. So I am upvoting your answer, but I can't accept it as a solution to this problem.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: A practically-identical solution that just doesn't reuse the instances would work fine. You'd have a `SemaphoreSlim` that restricts the number of allocated instances; it just wouldn't be a "pool".

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thank you for the upvote! I considered the problem a bit narrowly and when I hear 1GB bytesets I immediately go to pooling for the sake of LOH

Comment: Yep, it would be a pity not to use an array-pool in this case. But the problem presented in the question is contrived. Instead of `byte[]` I could have chosen something different as the `T` for the `Channel<T>`, like an unspecified `Blob` class.

Answer (score 1):

Buffered producer/consumer systems like channels and Dataflow are a little "fuzzy" around maximum buffer sizes (I can never remember if Dataflow counts items in output buffers or not). And as you point out, they don't count any items held by producers or consumers.

So, in order to restrict the *total* number of objects at any time, you'll need your own allocator.

```
public sealed class LimitedAllocator<T>
{
  private readonly SemaphoreSlim _mutex;

  public LimitedAllocator(int maxItems) =>
      _mutex = new(maxItems);

  public async Task<AllocatedItem> AllocateAsync(Func<T> create)
  {
    await _mutex.WaitAsync();
    return new(this, create());
  }

  private void Free() => _mutex.Release();

  public sealed class AllocatedItem : IDisposable
  {
    public AllocatedItem(LimitedAllocator<T> allocator, T item)
    {
      Item = item;
      _disposer = Disposable.Create(() => allocator.Free());
    }
    public T Item { get; }
    public void Dispose() => _disposer.Dispose();
    private readonly IDisposable _disposer;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var allocator = new LimitedAllocator<byte[]>(3);
var channel = Channel.CreateBounded<LimitedAllocator<byte[]>.AllocatedItem>(2);

var consumer = Task.Run(async () =>
{
  await foreach (var allocatedItem in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
  using (allocatedItem)
  {
    ... // Do something with allocatedItem.Item
  }
});

var producer1 = Task.Run(async () =>
{
  while (true)
  {
    var allocatedItem = await allocator.AllocateAsync(() => new byte[1_000_000_000]);
    ... // Do something with allocatedItem.Item
    await channel.Writer.WriteAsync(allocatedItem);
  }
});
```

Notes:

- The producer example assumes exceptions will cause an app failure. If exceptions must be recovered from, then the `...` in the producer needs a `try`/`catch` around it that disposes the allocated item only in the case of exceptions.
- In the case where the `T` in `LimitedAllocator<T>` is just memory (e.g., `byte[]`), you can consider using an `IMemoryOwner` instead of `AllocatedItem`. `IMemoryOwner` is essentially a disposable combined with memory.
- The producer no longer waits to see if there is room available in the *channel*; it just waits to see if there's room available in the *allocator*. If there's room available in the allocator, then that producer becomes the one that will create an item to send into the channel.
- If you strongly dislike the `AllocatedItem` pairing of `IDisposable`-with-item, then it's *possible* to use [connected properties](https://github.com/StephenCleary/ConnectedProperties). But that tends towards more magic and less maintainable code.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for the answer! What puzzles me with this solution is that the item (the `byte[]`) is constructed by the `LimitedAllocator` instead of the producer. The producer in my question is running on the `ThreadPool`, but in the general case it could be running on a dedicated thread (with sync context installed), and maintaining thread-affinity might be important. So delegating the responsibility of constructing the item elsewhere is undesirable. Is it possible to modify this solution so that all the construction work is done exclusively by the producer?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: The producer calls `LimitedAllocator.AllocateAsync` to construct the item; there's no different threads or anything like that involved. I would say the producer *is* constructing the item; it's just doing so via a helper method.

Comment: The `LimitedAllocator` does not invoke the `create` lambda synchronously, but asynchronously after awaiting the `_mutex.WaitAsync()`. This makes things hairy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach, which also uses a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) like in [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73914351/11178549)'s and [to11mtm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73902165/11178549)'s answers. The difference is that the `initialCount` and `maxCount` of the semaphore are initialized to the exact capacity of the channel, and the semaphore is released by the consumer immediately after a `byte[]` is taken from the channel, not when it's fully processed:

```
const int capacity = 2;
Channel<byte[]> channel = Channel.CreateBounded<byte[]>(capacity);
SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new(capacity, capacity);

Task producer1 = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            byte[] array = new byte[1_000_000_000];
            // Here initialize the array...
            await channel.Writer.WriteAsync(array);
        }
        catch
        {
            semaphore.Release();
            throw;
        }
    }
});

Task consumer = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await foreach (byte[] array in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync())
    {
        semaphore.Release();
        // Here consume the array...
    }
});
```

Essentially the `SemaphoreSlim` becomes the guard that limits the capacity of the channel. You might as well use an unbounded channel if you want.

This approach ensures that the maximum number of `byte[]`s allocated at any time will be 3, excluding those that are eligible for garbage collection.